# disable purticular checkbox in primeng multiselect

Tags: angular5, primeng

res.employee.data.role.forEach(role => { this.roleadd = { label: role.display_name, value: role.name } this.roles.push(this.roleadd); });

```
<p-multiSelect [style]="{'width':'100%','z-index': '1'}" [options]="roles" [(ngModel)]="model.role" [formControl]="form.controls['role']"></p-multiSelect>
```

Answer (score 0):

`SelectItem` has `disabled` property. You need to set `disabled = true` to disable on dropdown

```
this.roleadd = { label: role.display_name, value: role.name, disabled: true }
```

Comment: can you create stackblitz demo?